# Method adding multiple items to ListView rather than one.

Tags: c#, xaml, listview

I can't work this out at all. The following two methods are stripped down methods of something in my project which I'm using to debug an issue.

I have a XAML textbox control acting as a search field and this method is intended to listen for when a user presses a return key to submit a search. When the return key is pressed a item should be added to a ListView control I have on my page.

Below are two versions of the method, the first listens specifically for the return key however this produces an error where by the searched term is added TWICE to the ListView.

```
// Adds two items to ListView
    public void OnSearchKeyPressDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListView termsList = termsListContainer;
        if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
        {
            termsList.Items.Add(searchTerm.Text);
        }
    }
```

The version below is a test which listens for ANY key. This one works correctly and adds just a single item to the ListView.

```
//Adds only one item to ListView
    public void OnSearchKeyPressDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListView termsList = termsListContainer;
        termsList.Items.Add(searchTerm.Text);
    }
```

I cannot for the life of my figure out what in the first method is duplicating the items being added - could someone please help me out, I'm sure it will be simple and I'm overlooking an obvious thing.

Cheers.

Comment: Just to add further clarification, if I change the key that the method is listening for to something else like 'a' it adds only one ListView item too, so it is something to do with listening for the Enter key.

Comment: How many times is the first function called when you hit enter? (put a breakpoint in it and see how many times it is hit, or add a logging statement).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've actually just added an answer which I found elsewhere - not sure it's something I would have ever found on my own! Also not sure I should answer my own question :-s

Comment: Answering your own question is acceptable - you even get a minor badge for it if you accept your answer I believe.  Glad to see I was on the right track thinking that the Enter key was triggering the callback more than once.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've managed to find the answer with further investigation - not sure if I am meant to answer my own question or not but I found it here and it appears to be a bug Microsoft is aware of.

[MSDN Article on Keydown on Enter bug](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/734d6c7a-8da2-48c6-9b3d-fa868b4dfb1d/c-textbox-keydown-triggered-twice-in-metro-applications?forum=winappswithcsharp)

Here is one of the workarounds mentioned in the post:

```
if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
{
    if (e.KeyStatus.RepeatCount == 1)
    {
        //code you wish to call
    }
}
```